# How do I animate the background opacity but not the border with a herited color

Tags: html, css, css-animations, opacity

Is it possible to animate only the background opacity of an element ?

```
background: rgba(inherit, inherit, inherit, .8);
```

Here is the jsfiddle of what I want to do : http://jsfiddle.net/wqvscom2/

Thanks :) !

Comment: I confess I'm not really clear on what you are trying to do. Perhaps a more detailed explanation would help.

Comment: @Paulie_D I want to use a css3 animation from a background opacity to an other. The problem is that I can't guess the background rgb color because a class is added by a script.